# Flash AS3 Maze Type Game Issue

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've created a maze game in Flash as3 and it all works great as an individual swf. As soon as I drop it into the main container swf it stops working! Well, it still kind of works, but it loses the 'bounds' of the maze. Does anyone know how I could fix this problem please? Any help greatly apprecaited, S.

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.*; 
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import gs.TweenLite;
import gs.easing.*;

public class slide17 extends MovieClip {        
    private var maze:mazeBG;    
    private var mazeC:mazeCircle;   

    var rightArrow:Boolean = false;
    var leftArrow:Boolean = false;
    var upArrow:Boolean = false;
    var downArrow:Boolean = false;
    var speed:int = 10;

    public function slide17():void {
        screen01();                 
    }

    private function screen01():void {      

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, stage_onKeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, stage_onKeyUp);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, stage_onEnterFrame);

        maze = new mazeBG();
        addChild(maze); 
        maze.x=88;
        maze.y=155;                 

        mazeC = new mazeCircle();
        addChild(mazeC);    
        mazeC.x=104;
        mazeC.y=321;    

        function stage_onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) rightArrow = true;
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) leftArrow = true;
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) upArrow = true;
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) downArrow = true;
        }
        function stage_onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) rightArrow = false;
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) leftArrow = false;
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) upArrow = false;
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) downArrow = false;
        }
        function stage_onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
            var rect:Rectangle = mazeC.getBounds(stage);                
            var i:int = 0;
            var xBump:int = 0;
            var yBump:int = 0;
            if(rightArrow) {
                xBump = speed;
                for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
                    if(maze.hitTestPoint(rect.right + i, mazeC.y, true)) {
                        xBump = i - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(leftArrow) {
                xBump = -speed;
                for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
                    if(maze.hitTestPoint(rect.left - i, mazeC.y, true)) {
                        xBump = -i + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(upArrow) {
                yBump = -speed;
                for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
                    if(maze.hitTestPoint(mazeC.x, rect.top - i, true)) {
                        yBump = -i + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(downArrow) {
                yBump = speed;
                for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
                    if(maze.hitTestPoint(mazeC.x, rect.bottom + i, true)) {
                        yBump = i - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            mazeC.x += xBump;
            mazeC.y += yBump;
        }

    }           

}
 }
```

Comment: Could you better define "bound"?

Comment: I think the problem is that you get your bounds from the stage. var rect:Rectangle = mazeC.getBounds(stage); When you run it alone, the stage is available to you. When you load the swf from another swf, it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line:

```
var rect:Rectangle = mazeC.getBounds(stage);
```

uses the stage object to get the area of your MazeCircle.  When you add your game to a wrapper swf (your main container swf), the stage object is now the stage of the wrapper.  If the wrapper has different dimensions than your game swf, your call to `getBounds()` is going to return funky coordinates.

What you need is something consistent to measure with that won't change when the stage object gets changed. There are a few ways you could fix this:

1. Use a `Sprite` or `MovieClip` to wrap your game, and use that with `getBounds()` instead of the stage. You could use the instance of `slide_17` that your working in by using the `this` keyword. Ex:

   `var rect:Rectangle = mazeC.getBounds(this);`
2. Use a function other than `getBounds()` to determine the area of your MazeCircle, for example, using the properties `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` instead.  Let me know if you would like an example of this, but I'm betting you can figure it out - it would be lengthy to include it here.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Many thanks for the answer Ian; unfortunately I can't get either ways to work - how would I go about getting option2 to work?